# How to loop through DocumentFragment's children?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I loop through `DocumentFragment` `childNodes`? I've tried doing the following:

```
console.log(result.childNodes);
console.log(result.childNodes.length);
```

But length seems to be 0 even if I can see the actual child nodes in firebug, like:

```
[div#tiptip_arrow]
0
```

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ve5hf/
This is not exactly what I'm doing, but demonstrates the problem: when I have a look in Firebug console, I see that the fragment has child nodes, but `console.log(result.childNodes);` yields `[]` for some reason. Why is that?

Comment: of course it has no child Nodes it's an empty document fragment. Note that the reason you see data in `childNodes` when you log `result` is because `console.log` is live.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var o = document.createDocumentFragment();
o.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
var childNodes = o.childNodes;
for (var i = 0, len = childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(childNodes[i].tagName);
}
```

[`.length` does work.](http://jsfiddle.net/3pxcG/)

We need more specifics. How do you create the document fragment? What browser?

Comment: Please have a look at the update. I'm trying to override createFragment, but fail to get the children.